# SQL query all data of last year & current year dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT COUNT(shipment) as count, country as Origin, country as Destination,SHIPMENT_DATE, SHIPMENT_STATUS
FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE SHIPMENT_DATE > TO_DATE('31-12-17','DD-MM-RR')
```

I want this query to be dynamic by taking all dates of last year and current year. So in 2020 it should only contain values of 2020 and 2019 and nothing of 2018 anymore.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sampke and the expected  result

Comment: What data format is the `SHIPMENT_DATE` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reformat by using `to_char(sysdate,'RRRR')-1` within `to_date()` conversion :

```
SELECT shipment_date, shipment_status, load_country_code, unload_country_code,
       count(shipment) as "count"
  FROM shipment
 WHERE shipment_date  >= to_date( concat('01-01-',to_char(sysdate,'RRRR')-1) , 'DD-MM-RR')
 GROUP BY shipment_date, shipment_status, load_country_code, unload_country_code
```

pay attention that I didn't compare only the year part but formatted as a date, since in this way we do not unveil the index on shipment_day column if exists any.

Or another option would be replacing

`WHERE shipment_date  >= to_date( concat('01-01-',to_char(sysdate,'RRRR')-1) , 'DD-MM-RR')`
with

`WHERE shipment_date  >= trunc(add_months(sysdate,-12),'RRRR')`

alternatively

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3dcc31f30947b14f3a0efeca2b7af87)</kbd>

Comment: Hey this solution seems to work my dates start at 02-01-18 and end at 01-11-19. Now just to confirm when it's 2020 the dates if there are any shipments on that date at 01-01-19 and end at whatever date it is in 2020?

Comment: sure works for shipment_date >= '2018-01-01' ( of course for 2020 or for a later date ) @johnlogistic1

Comment: I can see you edited your msg with alternatives, I now use the first option. What exacly is the difference? I there a difference in performance or just shorter SQL code?

Comment: Both way are possible without performance issue, the second one is prettier as being shorter @johnlogistic1

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `COUNT` is not valid, because you are selecting other non aggregate columns without also using `GROUP BY`.  If we remove the count, we can try:

```
SELECT
    country AS Origin,
    country AS Destination,
    SHIPMENT_DATE,
    SHIPMENT_STATUS
FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE SHIPMENT_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' year, 'YEAR');
```

Comment: Oops sorry i stripped my query to hide identifying things but i do have a GROUP BY clause " GROUP BY SHIPMENT_DATE, load_country_code, unload_country_code, SHIPMENT_STATUS"  assume the query works i just need the date to be dynamic. Also in your solution will the formatting of the date be different? I use TO_DATE function cause if I don't I get an error in PowerBI saying invalid month etc etc

Comment: Is `SHIPMENT_DATE` actually a _text_ column?  Please edit your question and show us the real query.